# How to change opacity of other list items on click?

Tags: jquery, css

I am creating a page with a list of clickable items that scroll to div on click. I am looking for a way to change the opacity of the list items on click, so for example if you were to click the top list item the others would lower in opacity

I also want the list items to be highlighted (full opacity) while the user is on the corresponding div that the list item links to so that the list items change opacity as the user scrolls through the images on the right highlighting the list items as they scroll.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to achieve this or any examples?

```
$("#generationbutton").click(function() {
$('.wrapperright').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#generationanxiety").offset().top},
    1500);
});
```

Here is the pen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/drqWJv

Answer (score 0):

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pYOrOV

You can create a class with the opacity and remove it when the user clicks an item in the list.

```
$('.bio ul div').addClass('opacity');
$(this).removeClass('opacity');
```

The first line makes sure al the divs will get the opacity. The second line will remove it from the menu item you clicked.

For the scrolling part you need to get the scrollTop position of each div with a scroll listner and remove the opacity class from it when the user gets to that point.

Comment: Hey thank you for your reply. How would I have all the list items on full opacity on page load and only fade the others once clicked? Do you have any examples of the scroll listner function? I'm not familiar

Comment: @Sasha.Burger You just have to delete the opacity classes in your html. The opacity is then added when the first menu item is clicked. Hope it helps, good luck